# How to access Google Datastore IDs on the front end when info is returned via API response in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-datastore

I am working with React.js, Node + Express for API server, and Google Datastore.
I would like to query the Datastore and return back to front end the list of entities and their DB IDs.

When I run a regular Datastore query, the list of entities is returned without the IDs.

Based on https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.4.x/Query
I found that to access the DB IDs I need to use `results[0][x][Datastore.KEY]` to access each ID. 
Such approach is fine on the back end. 
However, how would you access the IDs on the front-end?

I can send the query output to front-end using

```
app.get('/example_url', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const query = datastore.createQuery('entity');
     datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
        res.send(JSON.stringify( {results }));
.....});
```

However, on the front end I can't access the IDs. I can't use the notation given for the back end. `results[0][x][Datastore.KEY]`
datastore is not defined on the front end.
Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I praticed Python in App Engine, so my answer won't be complete.

In Python you have to pass the key as a string to the front-end like that:
`my_key = YourObjectModel.key.urlsafe()`

To do it in JS, I think it should be: `YourObjectModel.key.id`

You have an example at the end of [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore)

Comment: Thank you. That helped. However, I expected a nicer solution from Google's team. It seems a waste to me to pass the IDs twice: once in the "results" (where the IDs are not accessible on the front end ) and once in yet another object that I have to create+update+pass

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found so far is:
on the back end iterate over the received key.id array/object. put these "id"s in a new array and send it to the front end together with the rest of the DB query results. Then the front end will have access to these "id"s.